# Unity shift origin to bottom left corner of the map

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm creating a 2D game in unity, but my origin is the center of the screen, meaning that my x and y values in the transform can be negative. I want to move the origin to the bottom-left, so my x and y values are always positive. How do I do that in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to move all my objects to the bottom-left of the game canvas, since the game canvas is what determiens all the objects positions -- not the camera!